# Big polyline and big polygon intersection

Tags: google-maps, geometry, intersection

Working with the Google Maps API, I want to compute the intersection of a polyline and a polygon. I recall that polyline and polygon are sets of consecutive segments, the only difference is that a polygon is closed.

My first guess would be to check if any segment of the polyline intersects with any segment of the polygon. However my polylines can have up to `1e4` segments and my polygons up to `1e5` segments. Testing every pair would be too long.

Any idea of how to do that in a smarter way?

Comment: Insert the larger one into a spatial hierarchy structure, e.g. KD-tree. This will give `O([size of smaller shape] * log[size of larger])`